# Missing features on WordPress Dashboard & Admin Bar

Tags: wordpress, elementor

For a while I have been missing "Edit with elementor" function in the admin bar. Now I noticed that some other functions like "header footer elementor" are also missing from admin bar. The other thing is that in Dashboard menu -> Appearance there is no "Editor" anymore. Any idea how to fix this issue? I have tried to reinstall WP through dashboard, but nothing changed...

Comment: Did you install Elementor plugin?

Comment: Check config file is there disallow file edit defined?

Comment: Yes, the elementor latest version installed and was re-installed, nothing changed. I can edit pages using Elementor, but I must go to backend, then click "Edit with elementor" instead of browsing the website and choosing on the frontend "edit with elementor" without going to backend first.. maybe the screenshot will better describe what is missing. Everyone who use Elementor will catch what is missing: http://prntscr.com/jqcq53

Comment: Try Clear and purge your cache plugin, see if admin bar shows normally.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the deal. I have a am hosting website on litespeed shared hosting server and I have litespeed cache plugin. Went to litespeed cache settings -> advanced view -> ESI -> Off (Detailed: http://prntscr.com/jqdogj).

About the "...in the backend dashboard menu -> “Appearance” the “Editor” selection is missing..." I went to iThemes security settings and disabled "Wordpress Tweaks". All is fine now!